# Removing duplicate characters from string using STL

Tags: c++, string

Is there a way to remove duplicate characters from a string like they can be removed from vectors as below

```
sort( vec.begin(), vec.end() );
vec.erase( unique( vec.begin(), vec.end() ), vec.end() );
```

or do I just have to code up a basic solution for it?
What I have thought:

I could add all the characters into a set

Comment: It's exactly the same for a string as for a vector.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "duplicate" characters.  Does a string `"ABACADAF"` have duplicate `A`s?  Or would you just want `"AABACAD"` to remove the first `A` in the double `AA`?

Comment: Why would you go for an `O(n log(n))` solution while you can do it in `O(n)` as explained [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-all-duplicates-from-the-input-string/) in the Second method?

Comment: Thanks turns out i was missing out the "str" part from str.erase(...) and was ending up with an error thinking this cant be done.. my bad..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The whole point of C++’ algorithm and container design is that the algorithms are – as far as possible – container agnostic.

So the same algorithm that works on vectors works – of course! – on strings.

```
std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
str.erase(std::unique(str.begin(), str.end()), str.end());
```

The same even works on old-style C strings – with the small difference that you cannot `erase` their tails, you need to manually truncate them by re-setting the null terminating character (and there are no `begin` and `end` member functions so you’d use pointers to the first and one-past-last character).