# Erase() doesn't work C++

Tags: c++, string, erase

Given a string named `question = " this      isn't a   relevant question , is it???     "`. You have to replace consecutive spaces by only one space. I have an idea using erase() in std::string but I don't know why it does not work. Here my code:

```
    for (int i = 1; question[i]; i++)
        while (question[i] == ' ' && question[i - 1] == ' ')
             question.erase(i, 1);
```

Comment: How does it not work? I pasted your code into a small minimal program and despite the creative stop condition in the loop the program does compile and remove consecutive spaces in the provided example (and some other edge cases I tested the code with) just fine.

Comment: The code works. Check here http://ideone.com/Dhrlgd

Comment: aw, I am using Visual Studio 2017, it absolutely does not work. Check it out: https://scontent.fsgn5-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/18156942_1901088013482746_4653484228107037735_n.jpg?oh=abdab264e0aa77f9a82a962e80a504a9&oe=5981638F

Comment: @NTNImperial the webpage on the given link is blank

Comment: @NTNImperial Do you get some kind of error message, compilation error? Can you describe _how_ it does not work, instead of simply stating that it doesn't? See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8ff974b7d3371e6 for a running example of your code.

Comment: The compiler do not blame any errors. "doesn't not work"  - does not execute as expected, I mean. I have been trying online IDE, it works, but in VS2017 or DevC++ in my computer, it doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicate characters from string using STL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121324/removing-duplicate-characters-from-string-using-stl)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't increase `i` if you've erased an element. If you do, you'll skip over elements.

Also, your fancy stopping condition will lead to undefined behaviour on a blank string, and in cases where the string ends with two spaces.

Comment: The `i` gets incremented whenever the string is not erased. (i.e. When it gets out of `while` loop)

Comment: @NTNImperial: Only when you've been doing this for far too long can you fix code "by sight". In the meantime, get your debugger out and fix it yourself. Debugging is more important than cutting code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unique` in `<algorithm>` in the following way.

```
std::string::iterator it = std::unique(question.begin(), question.end(), [](const char& a, const char & b) { return ((a == ' ') && (b == ' ')); });

std::string output_string(question.begin(), it);
```

Comment: That's a very elegant solution.

Comment: Indeed it is. Have an upvote. I couldn't resist sprucing up the language a little in the appreciation that English might not be the answerer's first language.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want C++, use regex.

```
#include <regex>
std::string question=" this      isn't a   relevant question , is it???     ";
std::string replaced = std::regex_replace(question, std::regex(" +"), " ");
```

Comment: Nice. If you don't mind I've added `std::` prefixes so the thing is more likely to compile "out of the box" without introducing `using namespace std` naughtiness.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Thank you!