# Find the different characters present in a string

Tags: c++, string

Is there any way to find the all the unique characters present in a string **without finding all the occurrences of the string** ? 
*For example, Let it be string a="mississippi" , the output should be {i,m,p,s}*. Is there any inbuilt functions to find that in c++?

Comment: How about using `std::set`?

Comment: But these characters are not unique. I think the title need to be paraphrased.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicate characters from string using STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121324/removing-duplicate-characters-from-string-using-stl)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that using `std::sort, std::unique, std::string::erase`

**Note** : original string will be modified [If you don't want that make a copy of it]

```
std::string str = "mississippi";
std::sort(std::begin(str), std::end(str));
auto last = std::unique(std::begin(str), std::end(str));
str.erase(last, std::end(str));
```

Comment: I think that's better than building a fully fledged `set` and ough to be faster.

Answer (score 2):

Make a [set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) of characters and put all items from string to it, then you will have set with "alphabet" of your string.

E.g.:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main(void)
{
    std::string a = "mississippi";
    std::set<char> alphabet;
    alphabet.insert(a.begin(), a.end());
    std::cout << "Set of chars has " << alphabet.size() << " items." << std::endl;
    for (auto a : alphabet)
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Original string is not modified in that example and there is no need to pre-sort.

Comment: One recommendation: Swap the documentation link to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set . It's a generally more complete and reliable source.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for suggestion - link was changed

Answer (score 0):

Sounds uncommon enough that it's not part of the STL.
I'd simply try iterating through the string and creating / incrementing the count of numbers in a Hashset.  Then, grab all the Keys to determine unique values.
Good Luck